# How to I remap the Emacs command M-d into the macro M-b, M-d?

Tags: emacs, keyboard-shortcuts, elisp

I would like the "delete to end of word" command to delete the word, regardless of cursor position.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
(defun my-kill-word ()
  (interactive)
  (backward-word)
  (kill-word 1))

(global-set-key (kbd "M-d") 'my-kill-word)
```

Comment: But what if you're at the beginning of the word? Then it will delete the previous word, won't it?

Answer (score 1):

A better code could be:

```
(defun my-kill-word ()
   (interactive)
   (unless (looking-at "\\<")
     (backward-word))
   (kill-word 1))

(global-set-key (kbd "M-d") 'my-kill-word)
```

So we move backward only if we are not at the beginning of the word
yet.

Comment: Thank you for this one. I've switched over to it. I'm enjoying my conversion to Emacs, but elisp is still gibberish.